# For a DataFrame with sorted, float index and columns, calculate a value using linear interpolation, based on a DataFrame values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, interpolation

I am working with a DataFrame having sorted float values of index and columns:

```
      9    15
5.0   2     9
8.0   3     1
```

I would like to use this DataFrame as a base to calculate a value for a given combination of index and column, for example (6.0, 12), where the values from the DataFrame will be taken for interpolation:

```
        9    12    15
5.0     2     -     9
6.0  (ci)  (ri)  (ci)
8.0     3     -     1
```

Where the (ri) values are calculated by interpolating values in the row, and (ci) values are interpolated using values in the column, and the middle value is the value we want to obtain. The order of calculation is to first calculate all the values in the row using the interpolation for relevant columns and then interpolate the final value in the row.

For the example above the values calculated will be the following:

```
         9    12    15
5.0      2     -     9
6.0   2.33  4.33  6.33
8.0      3     -     1
```

The value that we are looking for in this example is 4.33.

We can assume that the entry pair will always fall into the limits of the DataFrame index and column values, and it might also match the values, so for example for (5.0, 9) the return value should be 2.

Comment: To be clear, will your (ci) values be 2.5 and 5?

Comment: Good question. No, the interpolation should take the index and column values into account.

Comment: Could you provide your example with the (ri) and (ci) values filled in?

Comment: Good point, I realised that the specification was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try `numpy.interp`

```
l=[np.interp(6,df.index, df[x]) for x in df.columns]
np.interp(12,df.columns.astype(int), l)
Out[1140]: 4.333333333333334
```